# How do you have a hidden div appear and change sizes using css or jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

Say if you were to hover over a button, then another div will pop out and its background will change to a bigger size.

I've tried doing this using CSS transformation but the problem is I'd like the effect to instantly stop when the mouse isn't hovering over the button. What happens instead is after the div scales to a bigger size, it resizes to its original smaller size and *then* disappears. I used the visibility property to hide and show the div.

Deciding to fall back on jquery instead, I've already tried using animate() to resize the div's background image, but that is apparently not supported by jquery yet.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this effect?

**Edit:**

Here's a jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/dRF3r/1/

html

```
<div class="pointer">Hover
<div id="circle_bottom"></div>
<div id="circle_top"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.pointer {
    background: pink;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
#circle_bottom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: green;
    transition:           All 0.5s ease;
                    -webkit-transition: All 0.5s ease;
                    -moz-transition:    All 0.5s ease;
                    -o-transition:      All 0.5s ease;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#circle_top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: orange;
    transition:           All 0.5s ease;
                    -webkit-transition: All 0.5s ease;
                    -moz-transition:    All 0.5s ease;
                    -o-transition:      All 0.5s ease;
    visibility: hidden;

}
.pointer:hover #circle_bottom {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.1) skew(0deg) translate(0px, -10px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.1) skew(0deg) translate( 0px, -10px);
    -moz-transform:    rotate(0deg) scale(1.1) skew(0deg) translate( 0px, -10px);
    -ms-transform:     rotate(0deg) scale(1.1) skew(0deg) translate( 0px, -10px);
    -o-transform:      rotate(0deg) scale(1.1) skew(0deg) translate( 0px, -10px);
    visibility: visible;
}

.pointer:hover #circle_top {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.17) skew(0deg) translate( 0px, -10px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.17) skew(0deg) translate( 0px, -10px);
    -moz-transform:    rotate(0deg) scale(1.17) skew(0deg) translate( 0px, -10px);
    -ms-transform:     rotate(0deg) scale(1.17) skew(0deg) translate( 0px, -10px);
    -o-transform:      rotate(0deg) scale(1.17) skew(0deg) translate( 0px, -10px);
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Notice how the circles resize to a smaller shape before disappearing. Is there a way to get around this?

Here's the link to see the image of what I'm going for: http://i41.tinypic.com/2r1zrwm.jpg

My goal is when the pointer is hovered, the circle will show up and become a little bigger. The concept is stacking divs over each other.

Comment: css only should be fine. Can you show us some code perhaps?

Comment: Well, whatever you are currently doing... it doesn't work in IE9.

Comment: yes, here's the demo http://jsfiddle.net/dRF3r/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by just using this [jquery plugin](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/). You can also view this on [github](https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit)
Thanks for all of your time though.

Answer (score 0):

That can be achieved by having an onHover pseudo selector:

```
div:hover {}
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QWX8B/

Update:

with jquery animation:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/skGSF/1/
```

Comment: Nice and simple, but it doesn't animate -- just an on/off change.

Comment: Check the update. You'll of course have to modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: Why oh why would you go for a CSS solution, and then break down to using jQuery like everyone else for animation?  Use [CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) instead.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica I agree with you that pure CSS is always the best solution. I was just trying to answer the "is not supported yet" bit. And we also need to bear in mind cross-browser compatibility. Jquery spares us the horror.

Answer (score 0):

If you want jQuery you can use `hover` event and `animate` method

```
$('div').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        "border-width": "20px"
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        "border-width": "10px"
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dRF3r/)

Answer (score 0):

I forked Jeevan's example and used [jQuery Animat](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)e. Using jQuery animate will do the trick for you. Assuming your button has an ID and circle has a class.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").hover(function () {
        $(".circle").animate({
            height: "+=100",
            width: "+=100"
        }, 5000);
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abrudtkuhl/bZP94/

Comment: Also note: animate() won't show a hidden div. If it's hidden you'll need to chain on the .show() method before the animate() method. I can give you an example if needed.